# Bash Script error: [: missing ]

Tags: bash, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ `date +%u` -lt 6 && `date +%H` == '19' ] ; then
   echo 'Sorry, you cannot run this program today.'
else
   echo 'yes, you can run today'
fi
```

The script above is to run a program on weekdays and every 7PM. I have check the spaces and it still return error : date.sh: 2: [: missing ]

Answer (score 6):

Change it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ `date +%u` -lt 6  ] && [ `date +%H` == '19' ] ; then
   echo 'Sorry, you cannot run this program today.'
else
   echo 'yes, you can run today'
fi
```

Note that the `[` is just a shorthand for the `test` command and `]` the last argument to it. The `&&` operator is used like in any other command line, for example `cd /home && ls`

Comment: I've tested the same code and it worked. Are you sure your shell is *bash* ? which bash version?

Comment: sicksand@awalfathi:~$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.25(1)-release

Comment: me too. can you post the script you are currently trying to pastebin?

Comment: awesome! this is the same as my - working - code. Make sure that there are no hidden chars like windows line feeds in the file

Comment: If unsure use `fromdos script.sh`

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems with your code.

The first is a simple typo: `date %H` should be `date +%H`.

The second is the cause of the error you're seeing: `&&` isn't the right operator to use. It separates commands, whereas your `if` condition should really be a single one; bash looks for ] at the end of `` [ `date +%u` -lt 6 ``, doesn't find it, and errors out. You want to use `-a` instead.

Comment: [code]#!/bin/bash
if [ `date +%u` -lt 6  -a `date +%H` == '19' ] ; then
   echo 'Sorry, you cannot run this program today.'
else
   echo 'yes, you can run today'
fi
[/code]

return date.sh: 2: [: 13: unexpected operator

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong, but both my solution and @hek2mgl's are syntactically correct and work. The `13` it's complaining about is the result of ```date +%H```; I can't imagine why.